# Handle NavigatorIOS ButtonPress in the opened component

Tags: ios, react-native

I have NavigatorIOS in my app and I open a new Page like this and it works fine:

```
  var createProgramRoute = {
    component: CreateProgramPage,
    title: "Create Program",
    rightButtonTitle: "Save",
    onRightButtonPress: () => {
      // This part needs to be handled in CreateProgramPage component
    },
    passProps: {},
  };
  props.navigator.push(createProgramRoute);
```

CreateProgramPage class is like this

```
var CreateProgramPage = React.createClass({
  ...

  _onRightButtonClicked() {
    console.log("right button clicked")
  }

});
```

So I want to call **_onRightButtonClicked()** of **CreateProgramPage** when the RightButton of the NavigatorIOS is clicked. There is no example like this. All they have in examples are calling **pop()** of the navigator and that's it.

Comment: pass the handler down to the child component via a prop

Comment: Could you give an example please? Because if I pass a function with props, that function will be a reference to a function of the previous page.

Answer (score 2):

A. In initial component

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'title',
    component: MyComponent,
    rightButtonTitle: 'rightButton',
    passProps: {
        ref: (component) => {this.pushedComponent = component},
    },
    onRightButtonPress: () => {
        this.pushedComponent && this.pushedComponent.foo();
    },
});
```

B. In pushed component 
replace onRightButtonPress func in pushed component.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    // get current route
    var route = this.props.navigator.navigationContext.currentRoute;
    // update onRightButtonPress func
    route.onRightButtonPress =  () => {
        this._onRightButtonClicked();
    };
    // component will not rerender
    this.props.navigator.replace(route);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use some sort of Flux implementation with Actions that can be called from anywhere.

My personal favorite is Redux: https://github.com/gaearon/react-redux

The docs for the upcoming 1.0 release are really wonderful. http://gaearon.github.io/redux/